# How to edit tomcat server.xml in multiple folders using andible

Tags: xml, tomcat, ansible, devops

There are total 4 tomcat folders (tomcat_1...tomcat_4)

How to edit /tomcat_1...4/conf/server.xml

```
<Server port="{{change_here}}" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, remark that since many years shutting down Tomcat using the _shutdown port_ provides no advantage compared to killing the process. In most usage scenarios you can use `-1` as port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions.

You can make your `server.xml` a template and use [Template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) module. But if you just want to replace one value inside a big file, this may be an overkill.

So you can try using one of the following Ansible Modules

- [Replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html),

> This module will replace all instances of a pattern within a file.

- [Xml](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html)

> A CRUD-like interface to managing bits of XML files

There are several examples that may be useful for your use case.